# Unable to connect to my ec2 instance after setting ELB on Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

Recently i finished setting up my website using WordPress Bitnami Image, i configured the DNS servers as requested into my domain, pointing it to Amazon's NS servers, and also inserting the EC2's IP into the A type.

Everything is perfect, i can access my website through my domain's name, instead of using EC2's IP address.

But i came across with a request from my client, to implement HTTPS/SSL connection into the website.
So i created a Certificate through Amazon Certificates, validated it using my email address.

Here comes the part that is driving me crazy, i setup a Load Balancer to my EC2 instance, with the security group in use, and also selecting the Certificate created earlier with Amazon, so when i went to Route 53 and change the A type to point to my Load Balancer, the website becomes inaccessible:

This site can’t be reached

www.mydomain.com refused to connect.
Search Google for cegroup br restrito
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But it does work if i insert EC2 instance IP into A again, but i would not have a secure connection.

Please i need some help.

Ceers

EDIT:

I don't see this option to check as healthy. About the security group, is the one that WordPress Bitnami provides during the EC2 instance setup. Security Group configuration:

INBOUD 
HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0 
SSH - TCP - 22 - 0.0.0.0/0 
HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0

OUTBOUND 
All Traffic - All - All - 0.0.0.0/0

And the ELB Listeners:

HTTPS:443 
Security Policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08 
SSL Certificate: Default (The one i choose when i created the certificate at the ACM) Rules: Default forwarding to target group

Comment: Does your load balancer list the target instance(s) as healthy? What do you mean "with the security group in use"? Please provide the exact configuration of the security group assigned to your load balancer, and the security group assigned to your web servers. Also provide the ELB listener configuration.

Comment: Hi there, i don't see this option to check as healthy. About the security group, is the one that WordPress Bitnami provides during the EC2 instance setup.

Security Group configuration:
INBOUD
HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0
SSH - TCP - 22 - 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0

OUTBOUND
All Traffic - All - All - 0.0.0.0/0

And the ELB Listeners:
HTTPS:443
Security Policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
SSL Certificate: Default (The one i choose when i created the certificate at the ACM)
Rules: Default forwarding to target group

Comment: Edit the question to add that information in a format that is readable. Are you using a classic load balancer or an ALB or NLB? You need to figure out how to see the health check status of the instances in your load balancer before you continue.

Comment: Hi, just edited the question. Im using ALB, but the first time i did, was the Classic LB, and im pretty sure i could see the health status

Comment: You need to look in your Target Group to see the health check status of an ALB.

Comment: It says "Unhealthy" somehow, no idea what it could be, the website works perfectly. Also it says "None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target. Requests are being routed to all targets." I don't understand this

Comment: So what is your load balancer listener configuration? Your target group health check configuration?

Comment: Yes it is set to my target group health, very strange this... i took a screenshot for you to have a better look https://i.imgur.com/YVCvHXj.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your target group is pointing to port `443` on the EC2 instance. But the EC2 instance doesn't have an SSL certificate on it (the SSL certificate is on the load balancer), so it is most likely listening on port `80`. Try changing your target group configuration to point to port `80` on the EC2 server.

Comment: Oh so that's why the SSL wasn't working, is it possible to get the cert and key files to update it on my EC2? Also I changed the port to 80, good news is i can access the website through the DNS name from the ALB, but it still does get "unhealthy" status, the tooltip gives code error 301. Do you think i need to have a S3 bucket for it?

Comment: No AWS certs can't be installed directly on EC2 instances. 301 is not an error it is a redirect. Your S3 question makes no sense.

Comment: But is it possible to make a https/ssl connection to my ec2 without AWS certs? or should i buy a cert from another service? The reason im trying to establish a connection with the load balancer is to implement a secure connection

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is unclear. Are you trying to setup SSL on yor load balancer, to provide a secure conection for users? Or are you trying to setup SSL on your EC2 server for some reason?

Comment: The reason im trying to setup a ssl is for a secure access to private files for a company, through my website. Im a bit confused about AWS Certificate, but im getting it now. So i got an ELB working, the problem was with the health check, the path was wrong, i tried to point to index.php but wasn't working, so i created an empty HTML file and pointed it to, and now it works!

Comment: Having an SSL certificate on the load balancer provides secure access. Adding an SSL certificate on the server would simply add a layer of encryption between the load balancer and the server. Unless this is required for some regulatory purpose this is generally not done because the traffic between the load balancer and the EC2 server is confined to your VPC already.

Comment: Oh i see, having it on the load balancer should be enough, so i created an ALB with both HTTP and the HTTPS protocols attached to my AWS Certificate, and now i have a secure connection to my website as it shows the green lock at the browser's url